# UnwindtoMain gives nil error

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I'm getting nil error when trying to go back from one view to another view. When I click back button in first tableviews (right side of mainview), It gives this error. However, when I go second table view, I can go back to first tableview then I click back button It goes to MainView also. I searched It but couldn't find any solution. I also have a login screen on the left side of mainview and It also has unwindmain function.

```
    //Unwind
@IBAction func unwindToMain(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Unwind")
}
```

error;

```
 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-04-26 23:39:38.880674+0300 mySignals11[2107:448140] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint to identify the line it is crashing on and show that code

Comment: It doesn't give any error on MainViewController class. I have a breakpoint on start of viewdidload.

Comment: In the exception navigator, click the "+" and add a breakpoint of type "exception". Once you have the line it is crashing on you work out what is nil and why.

Comment: It says object_exception_throw